# How can I determine how much RAM and Processer each RDP session is using on a terminal server

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I currently have 4 Terminal Server "in a cluster environment" each employee starts an RDP session to to do their daily work.

Now, my company is expanding and we need to add more users. What I need to do is to see how many more terminal server I need "if any" to be able to handle the new users.

For testing, my idea is to ask one user to open all the programs that the users at the same time and they figure out how much RAM and processor that session is using. if I can figure that much then I can do some math to approximate how many users can each server happily handles. they I will be able to tell if I need more servers.

**My question is:** How can I check how much RAM and PROCESSOR a single session on the terminal server is using. with

my current server have 32GB installed RAM and Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2440 0@ 2.40GHz 2.4GHz with Windows Server 2008 R2
thank for your help

Comment: Since you have 4 servers in a production setup, I would be strongly tempted to **disable one, or maybe two and see what impact is has.**  Looking at a single user just doesn't make a lot of sense.  I am assuming you have already planned for some redundancy, so test it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll do better to approach this holistically - monitor all of the servers, including active connected RDP session count. Then divide the total performance numbers at any given time, by the number of users at the same time, to get your per-user resource usage.

/Edit - d'oh. Of course that doesn't count resource usage of the OS, which is what the performance numbers look like when session count is 0.

You should also be tracking these metrics with something like Perfmon, or Nagios, or Solarwinds - not by logging in and looking at Task Manager from time to time.

Doing an artificial test like you described won't be a true reflection of

1. How many resources that actual user uses or
2. What the average user session looks like.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand the method. so I just logged into "Remote Desktop Service Manager" of the server. I can see there is 32 active sessions. Then when looking as "Windows Task Manager" I see that 8GB of RAM is being used and 11% of processor. does this mean that on average each user is using 256kb of RAM? this just sounds small.

Comment: Edited my answer. And check your math - 8 GB / 32 users is about 256 MB, not KB.

Comment: yes that is a typo :) thanks for the correction and for your help.